# Roots of $x^6+tx^3+t$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I am trying to figure out what the roots are for a $x^6+tx^3+t$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$. The hint given is that the roots of this polynomial are "related to roots of a qudratic polynomial".

I am not even sure to approach this polynomials, looking for some pointers. I am not sure if the quadratic polynomial I should consider is just $x^2+tx^+t$ or something, although I am not sure how I can even justify that in the first place.

Comment: $x^6+tx^3+t=4x^6+4tx^3+t^2+t-t^2=(2x^3+t)^2+t-t^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $$x^3=z$$ then you will get $$z^2+tz+t$$