# Degree of splitting field of $x^6+tx^3+t$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I'm trying to find the degree splitting field of $x^6+tx^3+t$ in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$. After substituting $z= x^3$, and using the qudratic formula, and thensubstituting $x$ back in, I get the roots

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{-t\pm\sqrt{t^2-4 t}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}},$$
but how do I find the minimal polynomial for this? No matter what power I take, I can't seem to get rid of the radicals. Is there another way to think about square/cube roots when you are in a finite field? Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Apply Gauss lemma to jump from irreducibility in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$ to irreducibility on $\mathbb{F}_3[t][x]$, and then Eisenstein to $x^6+tx^3+t$ ($t$ divides all coefficients except the leading and $t^2$ doesn't divide the constant term).

Comment: Right, that makes perfect sense. How do I conlclude something about the degree of the splitting field. I think the roots here are given by the third roots of unity times the two roots we get from the quadratic formula. Since a primitive root of unity will generate the others, i think its enough add one my roots and a primitive root of unity. But Im still not sure how to compute the degrees of that

Comment: Root of unity, singular. $x^3-1=(x-1)^3$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's right. I am a little bit confused, what are the other 4 roots then, is it not true that an $n$ degree polynomial will have $n$ roots in some algebraically closed field? (or is that just for $\mathbb{C}$ specifically?) 
In any case, my understanding now is that adjoining one of the roots i mentioned is sufficient, and so the splitting field has degree 6, is this correct? Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: No, at most $n$ roots, and $n$ if you count multiplicity. In characteristic zero you know that if the polynomial is irreducible then the roots are distinct. But in positive characteristic that stops being true.

Comment: See also the question [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738485/roots-of-x6tx3t-in-mathbbf-3tx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jyre says, the polynomial $X^6 + tX^3 + t$ is irreducible, so you can make a first field extension of degree $6$. $\Bbb F_3(t) \to k = \Bbb F_3(t)[x]/(x^6+tx^3+t)$.

Over this field $k$, $x$ is a root of $X^6 + tX^3 + t$ so the polynomial factors a bit. It turns out $x$ is a multiple root :

$X^6 + tX^3 + t = X^6 + tX^3 +t - (x^6 + tx^3 + t) 
\\= X^6-x^6 + t(X^3-x^3) = (X^3-x^3)(X^3+x^3+t) 
\\= (X-x)^3(X^3+x^3+t)$

Now you need to check if $X^3+x^3+t$ is further reducible over $k$.

But putting $t = -x^6/(x^3+1)$, $k$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_3(x)$, and now the remaining cubic factor is $X^3 + x^3-x^6/(x^3+1) = X^3+x^3/(x^3+1) = (X+x/(x+1))^3$

Therefore, your polynomial splits in $k$ as $(X-x)^3(X+x/(x+1))^3$

And so the splitting field is $k$, and the degree is $6$.

Comment: (Thanks for pointing out that $t^{1/3}\in\Bbb F_3(t)(x)$. I hadn’t seen this.)

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a slightly different take on the problem, using the method recently recommended by Dietrich Burde somewhere. Calling $f(X)=X^6+tX^3+t$, we have $F(X)=g(X^3)$, $g(X)=X^2+tX+t$, quadratic, so that one root generates a Galois extension of the base field $k=\Bbb F_3(t)$. The roots are
$$
\zeta=\frac{-t\pm\sqrt{t^2-4t}}2=t\pm\sqrt{t^2-t}\,,
$$
in particular, the two roots $\zeta_1,\zeta_2$ are related by $\zeta\mapsto-t-\zeta$, an involution.

The roots $\xi_i$ of $f$ satisfy $\xi_i^3=\zeta_i$, so there are only two of them. Just as $g$ factors as $g(X)=(X-\zeta)(X+t+\zeta)$, so $f$ factors as $f(X)=(X^3-\xi^3)(X^3+t+\xi^3)=(X-\xi)^3(X+t^{1/3}+\xi)^3$, if only $t^{1/3}\in k(\xi)$, but it is, since $t=-\frac{\xi^3}{1+\xi^3}$, so $t^{1/3}=-\frac{\xi}{1+\xi}$.

Thus all (both) roots of $f$ come when you adjoin one $\xi$, and $k(\xi)$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $k$, degree six.